# ¿Se puede precargar un valor antes de que un usuario realice una busqueda en select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Lo que necesito es que select2 envíe un parámetro al inicializarse para que mi archivo al que realiza las búsquedas le devuelva la opción seleccionada sin que el usuario tenga que interactuar primero.

Mi código hasta el momento es:

Jquery: v3.2.1
Select2: v3.5.2

```html
<input type="text" name="diagnostico" id="diagnostico" class="form-control selector" value="999" placeholder="MyLabel" >
```

```javascript
    $(".selector").select2({
        placeholder: 'Selecione un diagnóstico',
        minimumInputLength: 2,
            ajax: {
                url: my_route,
                type: 'post',
                delay: 350,
                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        value: params,
                    }
                    return query
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            }
        });
```

He encontrado otras maneras de hacerlo como por ejemplo:

```javascript
    $('#selector').val(999);
    $('#selector').trigger('change');

    $("#e6").select2('data', {id: '999', text: 'MyLabel'});
```

Sin embargo estas consisten en traer los datos con anterioridad y no cumple que lo que yo estoy tratando de lograr. ¿No hay otra alternativa?

Comment: incluye el html para ver el contexto completo

Comment: qué diferencia habría entre precargar y traer los datos con anterioridad?